Counterexamples to limits using $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition?
Are there any references that show counterexamples to limits, based on the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition?
For example, suppose a function is given as $f\left(x\right)=2x+3$ and we incorrectly "guess" that the limit as $x \rightarrow 1$ of $f\left(x\right)$ is $6.$  So, now I want to show that the limit $L=6$ is wrong using the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition.  However, I assume that the limit is correct when I start the proof.  I'm interested in seeing where the proof process "breaks down," so to speak.
The above is just an example to illustrate what I am looking for.  Is there a reference that shows examples like this, especially for more complicated functions?  I've done some exploration and haven't found much in this regard.  Thanks for any pointers.

@underflow.  Thanks for the comment.  I'm actually not looking to solve a specific problem (like the example I gave), but rather looking for a book or papers that show a variety of counterexamples with different functions.  Thanks again.

Hint: choose $\epsilon=1/2$ and then choose $x_{\delta}=1+min{1/4,\delta}$ for every $\delta>0$

In $1970$ there was Counterexamples in Topology, by Steen and Seebach.
Later came the similar Counterexamples in Analysis and Counterexamples in Calculus, by different authors.
Any of these three books might be good candidates.
In the first one,  various types of metric spaces are considered.   In the Calculus one, there's two sections on limits.
Mind you I haven't read any of these books.

$|(2x+3) -6| < \epsilon \iff$
$-\epsilon < (2x+3)-6 < \epsilon \iff$
$3-\epsilon < 2x < 3+\epsilon \iff$
$1.5 -\frac \epsilon 2 < x < 1.5+\frac \epsilon 2$
But if $1 < 1.5 -\frac \epsilon 2 < x$ we will be dead toast in the water, because $x$ is not arbitrarily close to $1$!
If $1 < 1.5 -\frac \epsilon 2$ then $\epsilon < 1$.
If we let $\epsilon < 1$.  We can't have $|x-1| < \delta \implies |(2x+3)-6| < \epsilon$ for any $\delta>0$.
For any $\delta>0$, all we have to do is pick an $x_0$ that is closer to $1$ then either $1+\delta$ or $1.5-\frac \epsilon 2$.  For example what if we pick, $x_0 = 1-\frac \delta 2$?
Then $1-\delta < 1-\frac \delta 2 = x_0 < 1 < 1 + \delta$.  So $|x_0 -1| < \delta$.
But $|(2x_0+3)-6| < \epsilon =\frac 12<1$ is certainly false.
$|(2x_0 +3)-6| =|2x_0 -3| = |2(1-\frac \delta 2) -3| =|-1-\delta|=1+\delta > 1 > \epsilon$.
So... we failed.  Big time!
======
Note... if we chose that actual limit of $5$ this would not be able to fail.
$|(2x+3)-5| <\epsilon \iff$
$-\epsilon < 2x -2 < \epsilon \iff$
$2-\epsilon < 2x < 2+\epsilon \iff$
$1-\frac \epsilon2 < x < 1 + \frac\epsilon 2\iff$
$|x-1| < \frac \epsilon 2$.
So for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta = \frac \epsilon 2$ where $|x-1| < \delta =\frac \epsilon 2 \implies |(2x+3)-5|<\epsilon$.
We succeeded despite all our efforts to try to fail.
